# KeystoneJS S3 Image Upload from TinyMCE WYSIWYG

Tags: amazon-s3, tinymce, tinymce-4, keystonejs

I can't seem to find any documentation on converting the KeystoneJS TinyMCE wysiwyg to accept image files to upload to S3. I have added the following to my init (some as a failsafe/testing):

```
'wysiwyg additional plugins': 'uploadimage',
'wysiwyg images': true,
'wysiwyg s3 images': true,
```

Upon investigation, it seems that Keystone recognizes 'wysiwyg s3 images' but is trying to activate the uploadimage plugin that no longer exists in node_modules/admin/public/js/lib/tinymce/plugins.

I am running Node@10.15.0, NPM@6.7.0, and KeystoneJS@4.0.0-beta.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating keystone from version `4.0.0-beta.5` to version `4.0.0` helped me to avoid the tinymce plugin problem.